# CRM + Accounting SAAS tool

Tags: invoicing, crm

I m looking for a simple **web app** that will handle the following:

- When a user registers on my platform he is automatically added on the CRM.
- In the accounting side of things he is also shown but as a non-paying user (as he hasn't paid yet).
- When he registers for one of our monthly plans the accounting software is updated with his details (what plan, how much he paid, what discount etc).
- An invoice is generated automatically and sent to the email address on file. The invoice can be customised to look exactly how we want it to look.
- If he updates his billing details the accounting software is updated as well.
- At this stage if I view the user on the CRM I can see all his details about past payments, what pricing plan he has selected.
- If a user cancels his subscription this is updated on the accounting software and the CRM.
- In the accounting software the finance guy can go in and input the expenses we have made.
- As a bonus it would be great if there is a payroll aspect as well.
- There is a very strong element around reporting and we can run any queries we like. For instance, get a matrix of client vs month to see who has paid what.

Is there such a tool?

Thanks
Yannis

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you need [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) (CMS) integration with [Salesforce](http://www.salesforce.com/) (CRM) where both solutions are quite advanced.

Using Drupal module [Salesforce Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/salesforce), the details of the user can be mapped into Salesforce fields (Salesforce Mapping) on register. More complex requirements between CMS and CRM you can define by using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) modules and [further modules](http://drupalmodules.com/). For more customization you may even [create your own](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules).

On CRM side, you can use many plugins as well or develop your own business rules (triggers, validations, classes) by using [Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex) code.